# Matching words with Regex (Python 3)

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I had been staring at this problem for hours, I don't know what regex format to use to solve this problem.

**Problem:**

Given the following input strings, find all possible output words 5 characters or longer.

1. qwertyuytresdftyuioknn
2. gijakjthoijerjidsdfnokg

Your program should find all possible words (5+ characters) that can be derived from the strings supplied.
Use http://norvig.com/ngrams/enable1.txt as your search dictionary.
The order of the output words doesn't matter.

1. queen question
2. gaeing garring gathering gating geeing gieing going
   goring

Assumptions about the input strings:

- QWERTY keyboard
- Lowercase a-z only, no whitespace or punctuation
- The first and last characters of the input string will always match
  the first  and last characters of the desired output word.
- Don't assume users take the most efficient path between letters
- Every letter of the output word will appear in the input string

**Attempted solution:**

First I downloaded the the words from that webpage and store them in a file in my computer ('words.txt'):

```
import requests
res = requests.get('http://norvig.com/ngrams/enable1.txt')
res.raise_for_status()
fp = open('words.txt', 'wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
    fp.write(chunk)
fp.close()
```

I'm then trying to match the words I need using regex. The problem is that I don't know how to format my `re.compile()` to achieve this.

```
import re
input = 'qwertyuytresdftyuioknn'         #example
fp= open('words.txt')
string = fp.read()

regex = re.compile(input[0]+'\w{3,}'+input[-1])   #wrong need help here
regex.findall(string)
```

As it's obvious, it's wrong since I need to match letters from my input string going form left to right, not *any* letters which I'm mistakenly doing with `\w{3,}`. Any help into this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels a bit like a homework problem. Thus, I won't post the full answer, but will try to give some hints: Character groups to match are given between square brackets `[adfg]` will match any of the letters a, d, f or g. `[adfg]{3,}` will match any part with at least 3 of these letters. Looking at your list of words, you only want to match whole lines. If you pass `re.MULTILINE` as the second argument to `re.compile`, `^` will match the beginning and `$` the end of a line.

Addition:

If the characters can only appear in the order given and assuming that each character can appear any number of times: `'qw*e*r*t*y*u*y*t*r*e*s*d*f*t*y*u*i*o*k*n*n'`. However, we will also have to have at least 5 characters in total. A positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=\w{5})` added to the end will ensure that.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/53ijnb/20160919_challenge_284_easy_wandering_fingers/ 
It's actually a challenge from reddit just for practice.

Comment: Peter but I need to match letters sweeping the word from left to right... `[adfg]{3,} matches letters in any order.

Comment: From pythons regular expressions documentation: `(?<=...)` Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for ... that ends at the current position. Thus `^qw*e*r*t*y*u*y*t*r*e*s*d*f*t*y*u*i*o*k*n*(?<=\w{4})n$` ?

Comment: Lastly is there a way to make it so that each character can appear just once?

Comment: `?` matches 0 or 1 repetition. `*` matches 0 or more repetitions.